# Single wrapping argument for function

Tags: go, arguments

I have 33 callback functions:

```golang
func Cb1() {}
func Cb2() {}
func Cb3() {}
func Cb4() {}
func Cb5() {}
// other 28 callbacks ...
```

All of them should be passed into one function. So, I did it in the most obvious way:

```golang
type fn func()

func My(Cb1 fn, Cb2 fn, Cb4 fn, Cb3 fn, Cb5 fn, ... and so on ...){
   Cb1()
   Cb2()
   Cb4()
   Cb5()
}

My(Cb1, Cb2, Cb4, Cb3, Cb5, ... and so on ...)
```

I'm sure I'm not the only one with sore eyes from the sight of this "train" of arguments.

In javascript I would just wrap them all up in a class/object and pass them as a single argument, like so:

```js
function My(cb = {}){
   cb.Cb1();
   cb.Cb2();
   cb.Cb4();
   cb.Cb5();
}

My({ 
   Cb1,
   Cb2,
   Cb4,
   Cb5
});
```

But how do we do this in Go?

Comment: You could do it the same way, wrap them in a data structure like a slice, map, or struct; or you could dig into the underlying problem, because this situation really shouldn't arise in Go. It looks like you're trying to write JavaScript in Go, which is going to lead to a lot of issues and really hard to read code.

Comment: Declare `function My(cb...func()) {}`

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon Burak Serdar's comment above, I would suggest Variadic functions arguments.

This would give you a "My" function like the following:-

```
// My invokes the supplied list of callbacks
func My(cbs ...func()) {
    for _, cb := range cbs {
        cb()
    }
}
```

You can see this and run it here:
https://play.golang.org/p/P3xDYN-1C7M